# Can't make navigable rendered component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have the next component, which is substituted into the data grid as rendered item.

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('{data.GetLink()}'), '_blank');">
```

The problem with click event, it doesn't work.

How correctly to make navigation VBox that url is substituted from the dataProvider collection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The click event isn't getting called at all? It should. Try putting a trace() statement in there.

Once you see the trace() statement, put a hard-coded url in there for testing:
click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://google.com'), '_blank');"

After that, change GetLink() to a property in the 'data' object: like data.link

Comment: Yes, you are right. Click event fire, but it with wrong url, link not substitute.
With hard-coded url it works good.

This code works great:
<mx:Text id="title" width="100%" fontWeight="bold" text="{data.GetTitle()}"/>

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but do you have a click event already registered with the datagrid?  If so then the event from the child will be canceled out...